# Dangling pointer in pthread_join?

Tags: c, pthreads, glibc, memory-management

According to [this](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_join.c;h=6a87a8b329c3e34a57d65e86d45fa97a5fdb2fe2;hb=master), pthread_join sets the output parameter **thread_return to pd->result, then frees pd. Is this okay and I am missing something, or is there a serious bug in glibc?

```
    /* We mark the thread as terminated and as joined.  */
    pd->tid = -1;

    /* Store the return value if the caller is interested.  */
    if (thread_return != NULL)
      *thread_return = pd->result;


    /* Free the TCB.  */
    __free_tcb (pd);
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, compilable testcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__free_tbc` does not free `pd`, but the thread's stack, ie `pd->tpp` (see also [here](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.17/pthread__create_8c_source.html#l00200l)). So `pd->result` still a valid pointer after these statements.

Comment: Thanks. Another thing that bugged me was that the pointer may be to the stack, but the man page clearly warns against it:

The value pointed to by retval should not be located on the calling thread's stack, since the contents of that stack are undefined after the thread terminates.

( - So the thread should use malloc.)

Comment: @danuker: The value pointed by `retval` can be either a global variable or allocated on the heap, since `pthread_join` deletes the stack. The `man` page is right.